# How does Minecraft handle textures with different sizes in a texture pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a texture pack for my personal use, and I want to make some of the textures a larger size (32x32) than the others (16x16). Will all of the textures still work inside Minecraft despite being sized differently?

Comment: Yes, I have done this in the past (texture sizes being 16x16, 32x32, and 64x64 all in one pack). It works perfectly :D

Comment: Of course, this is assuming **Java Edition**, which I see you've tagged the question with. In Bedrock Edition, it will *mostly* work, but double resolution item textures may appear too large when held in the player's hand.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it is Java Edition on a Macbook Air.

Comment: I have a resource pack where I dump everything into that comes to my mind and it's a huge mess, partially massively outdated, but still works. You can't break much with resource packs, so just try it!

Comment: I want to scale up the minecart and put flames on the side - I take that it still works on other not-block textures.